# Permutations in C

Tags: performance, c, combinatorics

I searched on the internet for an algorithm for permutations in C and I found the following function:

```
void permute(char *a, int l, int r)
{
    int i;
    if (l == r)
        printf("%s\n", a);
    else
    {
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
        {
            swap((a + l), (a + i));
            permute(a, l + 1, r);
            swap((a + l), (a + i)); //backtrack 
        }
    }
}
```

The link to the page is: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/

The function looks elegant and short but quite frankly, I don't understand how it works, so I decided to implement my own understanding of the problem and came up with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fn(char *str, int k, int n);

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "abcd";
    fn(str, strlen(str), strlen(str));

    return 0;
}

void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    char tmp;
    tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void fn(char *str, int k, int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            puts(str);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (i == n)
                    putchar('\n');

                swap(str + n - i, str + n - i + j);
                fn(str, i - 1, n);
                swap(str + n - i, str + n - i + j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, should I be using that function or my function? Is there any advantage to that function over my function, given that my function has two loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I be using that function or my function?
> Is there any advantage to that function over my function, given that my function has two loops?

Let us look at each.

**The l with it**

See any problem with `swap((a+1), (a+i));`?  That code swaps the wrong elements.  Correct code, like what is posted, is `swap((a+l), (a+i));`.  Moral of the story.  Do not use an object called `l`.  Too easy to confuse with `1`.  Makes review unnecessarily difficult - even when code is right.

Advantage: OP

**Unneeded `()`**

Both below are the same.  One [drier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) than the other.

```
swap((a+l), (a+i));
swap(a+l, a+i);
```

Advantage: OP

**Check the zero case**

Both work well enough with `""` (does not print anything), yet original code could have trouble with `permute("", 0, strlen("") - 1);` given `strlen("") - 1` is `SIZE_MAX`.

The `""` case deserves explicit definition.  I could see `f("")` printing one line of nothing - after all 0! is 1.

Advantage: OP

**Check the wide case**

With very long strings, longer than `INT_MAX`, code breaks down as `int` is insufficient whereas `size_t` is best for array indexing.  Yet time to print such a set of permutations is many times the [age of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_the_universe), so we will set aside this concern.

Advantage: Neither.

**Not `const`**

More useful to have a function that does not require a `char *`, but can work with a `const char *`

Advantage: Neither.

**Functional difference!: Extra lines**

OP's code for `"abc"` prints the below.  Original code does not print the extraneous empty lines

```
abc
acb

bac
bca

cba
cab
```

Suggest dropping the `if (i == n) putchar('\n');`

Advantage: Original

**Repeated test within loop**

Why test for `k==1` repeatedly?  Perhaps

```
void fn(char *str, int k, int n) {
  if (k >= 1) {
    puts(str);
    for (int i = 2; i <= k; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        swap(str + n - i, str + n - i + j);
        fn(str, i - 1, n);
        swap(str + n - i, str + n - i + j);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Advantage: Original

**Function name, parameter names**

Both are wanting in their declaration.  `fn` is not an informative name for printing string permutations.  What is `k`?  How it should be called lacks guidance on correct usage.

```
void permute(char *a, int l, int r) {
void fn(char *str, int k, int n) {
```

Perhaps instead a wrapper function? Then make `permute(), fn()` `static`.

```
void print_str_permute(char *str) {
  int length = (int) strlen(str); 
  permute(str, 0, length - 1); 
  // or 
  fn(str, length, length);
}
```

Advantage: Original

**[Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)**

I put a function counter in both approaches.  OP was O(n!) and apparently so was the original.  Thus OP's concern about "my function has two loops" did not worsen `O()`.

Advantage: Neither

---

Recommend: Use the best parts of the two.

For me, I would prefer a solution that worked with a `const char *`.